# How to display content in place of ImageView

Tags: android

I am new to Android and using source that makes an image float. But I want content, such as an entire layout, to float instead of image. I think I need to replace ImageView with something else and searched for some possibilities on Android Developers site but couldn't find one.
 What should I use in place of ImageView and setImageResource?

Here is my code:

```
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Float extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageView(this);

        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
...
```

Thanks!